# changing the width when running a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to coding, so thanks in advance for any assistance here.

I have a script that runs two functions on the same sheet.

Button2 contains a function (email_button2) that runs a SQL query and pulls info into columns A to D

Button1 also contains a function (email_button1) that runs a separate query and I want to pull this info in columns G to AA (21 columns)

Right now, when I click Button1, I get the following error: **Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 21**

Any idea what I should change or add to my script?

```
function data_button() {
// Logger.log(e)
var thisDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var helpers = thisDoc.getSheetByName("helper");
query = 
helpers.getRange(3,2).getValue().split(String.fromCharCode(13)).join(" ").split(String.fromCharCode(10)).join(" ") 
 // lastrow = helpers.getRange("lastrow").getValue()
 do_query(query,"data")
 }

function email_button1() {
// Logger.log(e)
var thisDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var helpers = thisDoc.getSheetByName("helper");
query = 
helpers.getRange(4,2).getValue().split(String.fromCharCode(13)).join(" 
").split(String.fromCharCode(10)).join(" ") 
// lastrow = helpers.getRange("lastrow").getValue()
do_query(query,"emails",11,7)
}

function email_button2() {
// Logger.log(e)
var thisDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var helpers = thisDoc.getSheetByName("helper");
query = 
helpers.getRange(5,2).getValue().split(String.fromCharCode(13)).join(" 
").split(String.fromCharCode(10)).join(" ") 
// lastrow = helpers.getRange("lastrow").getValue()
do_query(query,"emails",11,1)
}



function do_query(query,sheetname,startRow,startCol){  
//List of lists?
var url= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
var q = {"query":query} 
var options = {
 'method' : 'post',
 'payload' : q,
 'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // get feed
var response2 = response.getContentText()
var rows = response2.split(";;;")
var columnCount = rows[0].length

   var data = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){

    var row = rows[i].split('|||');
       data.push(row);
  }
  Logger.log(data)
var a = data[1]    
var thisDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet2 = thisDoc.getSheetByName(sheetname);
sheet2.getRange(startRow,startCol,200,4).clear()
sheet2.getRange(startRow,startCol, data.length, 
data[0].length).setValues(data);
//this line above designates column headers
//sheet2.getRange(12, 1, data[1].length, data[1] . 
[0].length).setValues(data[1]);
//Logger.log(data[0].length)
//Logger.log(data[0][0].length)
//Logger.log(data[0])
//  thisDoc.getSheetByName("helper").getRange("lastrow").setValue(data.length)     



}
```

Comment: I suspect your rows are not of the same length.  For setValues you need to pass a rectangular 2D array.  If any of the rows is too short setValues will not work.

Comment: Correct, the rows will be different for both queries.  is there any work around for the button1?

Comment: You have to pad short rows with blanks so that all rows are the same length.

Comment: Try keeping tracked of the row length in `data.push(row)` and then use the maximum of that length in `sheet2.getRange(startRow,startCol, maxLength, data[0].length).setValues(data);` I'm just guessing here @TheWizEd answer is probably better.  I might also try appendRows into a temporary sheet and then getDataRange() and delete the sheet.